# Gnerate random div widths between 150px and 300px

Tags: html, random, size

Does anyone know how I would generate random div widths?
They would need to be between 150px and 300px.

The height of the div is not important as the content I'm going to put inside should automatically stretch them.

Thanks!

---

### Currently using this code

```
<head>
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var x = Math.floor((Math.random()*150)+150);
    $('#stat').width(x+'px');
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="stat" style="float:left; background-color: red;">hello</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using javascript's `random()` and some `jquery` you can do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var x = Math.floor((Math.random()*150)+150);
    $('div').width(x+'px');
});
<div>hello</div>
```

Comment: The div receives no styling at all when executed :(

Comment: it's working on jsfiddle, and i gave it a background color so that the width can be visible, check it out http://jsfiddle.net/labibismaiel/Eg27V/

Comment: Ive checked yours and it works fine on that site, but on my site is just will not work :(

Comment: did you forget to include jquery in your page?

Comment: you have to include the jquery file, use <script src="jquery.js"></script> if the file is local, or <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script> if you want to use the online version, put it inside the head tag